# Electron app interacting with WebView drag-drop

Tags: javascript, webview, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, electron

I'm developing a (desktop) application in Electron (v1.6.2) that has a `<webview>` element (hosting 'guest' web pages) and a number of text fields, both `<textarea>` and `<input type="text">`.

We would like the user to be able to select text within the guest page inside the WebView and drag-and-drop it into the application's fields -- but, this isn't working.

Without doing anything special, I can select text in the guest page and drag-and-drop it into other applications outside of Electron.
E.g. -
Dropping it into a text editor, a text-field in a web-browser or my terminal window works fine.
It even works dropping it into a field in a *different* instance of my Electron application.
I can also drag text that is in the application, but not inside the WebView, and drop that in the fields Ok.

However, when dragging the text selected in the WebView, the fields in the application are not sensitive to events -- i.e. they receive no `dragover` or `drop` events, and focus does not switch to them as you would expect.

I've tried adding event handlers to the `<webview>` to intercept the mouse events (`mosedown`, `mousemove`, `mouseup`) in order to manually control things and tried to use `event.preventDefault = true` to disable the events from passing down to the guest page.

Everything behaves as I would expect util the moment when it is recognised that you are dragging text.  Visually, this is the moment when the pointer switches to a closed fist and a ghostly rectangle appears showing the selected text.  At that moment all mouse events cease to be received by the `<webview>` event handlers. It seems that the application is 'frozen' when text is being dragged.

Is there anything I can do about this?
It would work either to: -
 - prevent the WebView from actually dragging text, and for me to simulate it programmatically;
 - or to find a way to 'unfreeze' the application during the text-dragging, so that the fields are active, can see events and can receive dropped text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug present in Electron v1.6.2.
It is fixed in Electron v1.6.5, released at the end of March 2017.
I've now updated to the latest stable release, v1.6.11, and the issue is fixed.